# Attribute a Row, Nested Below (How to Show Proper Relationship in Table?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, nested-attributes

This is the most difficult question I've come to in the past few months of starting my Ruby on Rails journey.

It seems like many people would face it, but I can't find anything on the web that addresses this problem, which means my question is either insanely easy that I am thinking too hard or I am asking the wrong question. Please help me get to the right answer and/or the right question!

When a User submits a form it includes the attribute (quantified) and the nested attributes (result). When the User clicks on the index I want him to see that the quantified created a new column in the header row (for each new quantified instance it goes right horizontally across the page). Then for every result he submitted or later adds I want him to see the result create a new row in that column (going vertically down the page).

I hope I explained that well and didn't make it sound more confusing than it is.

Here's one variation of what I can get the table to look like using html tags:

[image]

Here's another variation:

[image]

But for whatever reason I can't get this, which is what I want:

[image]

I really have no idea at this point, because I've tried everything, what code you need to help me so instead of dumping it all here I will give it to you here via github: https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday

### **UPDATE**

Using Patrick's answer below I was able to get the table to look like this:

[image]

The problem with it though is if a User adds another quantified such as meditate (min) and includes more result rows then the row preceding it then the result will move left until it hits another column with that many rows or more. In the example above "2.1" should be in the meditate column, but instead it fell into the weight column.

### UPDATE 2.0

With Patrick's update below this is what it looks like now:

[image]

Thanks again for trying Patrick. You're the man for sticking it out with me this far. You mentioned bootstrap. I'll give that another look.

Thanks in advance for your help! I'll be forever in your debt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky because the data is column-wise but we need it row-wise. I'm not 100% sure I understand how the quantified data is laid out but the gist of the solution is, you need two separate loops since the heading `<thead>` and data `<tbody>` are in separate sections of a `<table>`. Let's re-work the table for averages:

```
<h2>AVERAGE</h2>
<%
  averaged_data_rows = {} 
%>
<%# averaged_data_rows should end up as:
  {
    0 => [result, result, result],
    1 => [result, result, result],
    etc.
  }
%>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
        <% if averaged.user == current_user %>     
          <th><%= averaged.name %> (<%= averaged.metric %>)</th>
          <% 
            averaged.results.each_index do |idx|
              averaged_data_rows[idx] ||= []
              averaged_data_rows[idx] << averaged.results.to_a[idx]
            end
          %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% averaged_data_rows.values.each do |row| %>
      <tr>
        <% row.each do |result| %>
          <td>
            <%= result.date_value.strftime("%m-%Y") %>
            &nbsp;
            <%= result.result_value %>
          </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

I was afraid of that. Another possibility is to leave the data column-wise and do floated unordered lists. It would be really helpful to use a grid-framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). But here is a quick and very dirty idea that could work (assuming you don't care that the Weight (pounds) column doesn't have an 02-2015 value so it's 03-2015 value is riding next to the other 02-2015 values):

```
<h2>AVERAGE</h2>
<div>
  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
    <% if averaged.user == current_user %>
      <%# 
        Inline CSS like this is generally frowned upon. I am using it
        here for demonstration purposes only. The best solution would
        be to use Bootstrap or something like it to get the side-by-side
        view on wide screens and top-to-bottom view on smaller screens.
        But I think that is outside the context of this particular question.
      %>
      <div style="float:left; width:200px;">
        <h4><%= averaged.name %> (<%= averaged.metric %>)</h4>
        <ul>
          <% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
            <li>
              <%= result.date_value.strftime("%m-%Y") %>
              &nbsp;
              <%= result.result_value %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick! We are almost there. I added the slight problem with your code above and hopefully you can help me fix it. Thanks again!!  Out of curiosity how did you know to figure out the answer?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli I updated my answer based on your comments. I have been working on web-sites for several years. This kind of data visualization problem is pretty normal. Almost every website that has a database has at least one place where the server side code loops over a result set to build a table.

Comment: I could imagine a lot of ppl going thru the struggle, I'm surprised how hard it is to do. I can't find anything on the web about it. Since you said that bootstrap is outside the scope of this question can you direct me to a resource of someone who used bootstrap for this purpose? I'm at a lost for what to do next. Or is there another way to tweak your answer to get to the intended answer? Thanks again Patrick.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli did the floating unordered lists not do what you want? This example from the Bootstrap site shows an example of a three column layout http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/.

Comment: I uploaded a pic of what the changes made the table look like. Would bootstrap allow the user to add as many columns and rows as he wishes depending on how many forms he submits and within those forms how many nested attributes he included? The example you provided looks like the columns are static and cannot be increased by the User. To step away from this specific question for a second, let me give you a greater view of my ultimate goal that I want the data table to function as: http://www.anthonygalli.com/quantify/

Comment: I used excel in the link. I would add columns and rows depending on what I'm quantifying and its results. I want Users to be able to have that flexibility in my webapp. I am asking the above question as one step toward helping get my data table to function and look as in the link. I got my form to work. Now I just need the index, but it seems impossible, yet I would have guessed it is a common place problem. Do you think we're on track to achieving this goal or have I been asking the wrong question or am  I coming off as too confusing?

Comment: I would be content though to launch the 1st version of the webapp with the table looking like my intended goal for this question and the 1st updated table (just without the results moving left to fill empty space) if my ultimate goal seems too daunting a task.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli sorry about that. I missed an important detail in my updated answer. Each result inside the <ul> has to be wrapped in an <li> (list item) tag. That should get them each onto a new line.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do. If you want the table view from your example link then I think you will need different data handling to force the date ranges on the data so you know when there is a hole in a column. However, if you want it to be dynamic, I think this unordered list solution may work better. It seems like this is an app people would want on their phone and an HTML <table> does not transfer to mobile very well; especially if it can have a large number of columns.