# How to Prevent <ul> from overlapping <div>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If a User creates a bunch of `<ul></li>:results</li></ul>` those bullets will overlap the `<div>` below it. How can we stop this from happening? Will you save the `<div>` before it's too late?!? dun dun dun

**index.html.erb**

```html
<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->

<div id="values" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>AVERAGE</b></h4></div>

  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
    <% if averaged.user == current_user %>
      <div style="float:left; width:150px;">

        <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %>
        <b><%= averaged.name %> (<%= averaged.metric %>)</b>
        <% end %>
        <ul>
          <% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
            <li>
              <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b.%y") %>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <%= result.result_value %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>

# The line breaks only work if the User only adds a few rows, but I want to encourage the User to creates as many rows as his heart desires.
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->
<div id="values" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>INSTANCE</b></h4></div>

  <% @instance_quantifieds.each do |instance| %>
    <% if instance.user == current_user %> 
      <div style="float:left; width:150px;">

      <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(instance) do %>    
      <b><%= instance.name %> (<%= instance.metric %>)</b>
      <% end %>

      <ul>
        <% instance.results.each do |result| %>
        <li>
          <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b.%y") %>
           &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <%= result.result_value %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>

  <div class="values-button">
  <%= link_to new_quantified_path, class: 'btn'  do %>
  <b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"</span></b>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but this seems to be an HTML/CSS issue, not related to Ruby. You'd probably get a better answer if you only presented the resulting HTML/CSS in a jsfiddle. As it is, people will have to fill the template with dummy data, hoping that they reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: Well, since you are using the `panel` component from Bootstrap, you should probably start by wrapping that `ul` in a `div.panel-body`.  I am not sure what you mean by the " bullets will overlap the `div` below it," but I see you have some inline css where you are floating the div, you might need to clear that float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a the code `<div style="float:left; width:150px;">`. this is what makes it overlflow to the div below it. `float` style takes it out of the normal flow of the dom (floats above the natural structure of the dom is a way of describing it) and the div below it doesnt pay attention to it. removing that line of code (you have it twice) will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks! I can see how that is the problem. Do you know how to fix it? I can't just take it out because I need it.

Comment: what do you need it for? is it that you want to keep the list just on the left side of the panel?

Comment: It keeps my columns in place when a User adds a new result. If you want the long answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267633/attribute-a-row-nested-below-how-to-show-proper-relationship-in-table/28268954?noredirect=1#comment44965562_28268954

Comment: if what i said in my previous comment is true, then you can just get rid of float, so the code would be `<div style="width:150px;">`

Comment: I tried taking it out, but then it made the multiple columns turn into just one long column so unfortunately I need it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/192/ is the implementation of `<div style="width:150px;">`

Comment: I need it. Is there any way to keep the float going and solve this question?

Comment: ok, i see what youre saying now, instead of `float:left`, try `display:inline-block` so itd be `<div style="width:150px; display:inline-block">` http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/193/

Comment: Thanks. That's closer to fixing the issue, but now each quantified column loads to touch the bottom of the panel instead of aligning as one row at the top.

Comment: try `<div style="width:150px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">`